# VBA how to write to/modify cells in a function

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite surprised that such a simple functionality seems to be unsupported in VBA. Say I want to write value `0.5` to the cell `E7` inside a **function** (not a sub!):

```vb
Public Function writeToCell() As Integer
    ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Value = 0.5
    writeToCell = 0
End Function
```

And when I call the function `writeToCell` in another cell say `F9`, there is a value error, and the writing statement fails to be executed.

Why can we not write to cells inside a function? Is there any workaround? My problem is that the values I will write to some pre-designated cells depend on some intermediate results calculated inside the function. So I will have to write to the cells inside this function when I call the function from the target cell in my worksheet.

Comment: That sounds really contradictory with the idea of Excel, and the performance hit will be serious, since you will write to cells every time your sheet recalculates.

Comment: To build on @PatrickHonorez's comment, it's probably better if you just use a sub that fires when a button is pressed (or a hotkey). UDFs aren't really designed to edit other cells

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I would say recalculating every time on refresh is feature of Excel, e.g. allows for "real-time" monitoring while you update the parameters. Besides this, I will never use Excel for any data analysis task because VBA and its native editor are so ugly to use...

Comment: @TimStack yes I am thinking about that. A button+sub is much easier, although not robust.

Comment: Not robust? Sure it is. You could even make use of a `Selection_Change` or `Worksheet_Change` event, or `Application.OnTime` to make the updating automatic and more frequent

Comment: @TimStack that's what I was talking about. Every time you make changes to the worksheet layout you'll potentially have to change your code. But I think there's no way to avoid this problem with Excel or VBA anyway.

Comment: Well there has to be some kind of consistency, that is the case with every code language. Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible, although a tad different then when doing the conventional way (that is, not through a UDF)

```
Function writeToCell() As Integer
    Evaluate "performwrite(" & Range("E7").Address(0, 0) & ")"
    writeToCell = 0
End Function

Sub performwrite(dest As Range)
    dest.Value = 0.5
End Sub
```